# Why "test <blah>" expression in bash is true?

Tags: bash

I have fairly often seen that `test <blah>` expression is used in examples for endless while-loops. For example `while [ 1 ]; do echo "will loop endlessly"; done`. `[ 1 ]` is same as `test 1` wich will always be true:

```
$ test 1
$ echo $?
0
$
```

However, expression does not need to be an integer, but can also be a word, e.g. `test [ blah ]`. Why are `test [ 1 ]` or `test [ blah ]` true, i.e. expression does not go through any actual tests, does it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's synoymous to using `-n` which tests if a string is empty or not:

```
test -n "$x"
```

And `1` and `blah` are non-empty strings so they give true expressions.

But it's not recommended at least when testing variables since a variable can contain an operator that's valid to `test` and results may go unexpected. Prefer using `-n` instead.

And as suggested by [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272470/why-test-blah-expression-in-bash-is-true/25272520#comment39380776_25272520), if creating an infinite loop is intended, better just use `while true` or `while :` as it's more clearly written and also skips unnecessary testing of expressions.

For `bash`, `for (( ;; )); do` may come more efficient as it doesn't call another builtin and doesn't keep testing `$?`.

Comment: Which means, interestingly, that `while [ 0 ] ; do ... ; done` is also an infinite loop. A simple infinite loop is more clearly written without using `[` or `test`: `while true ; do ... ; done` or `while : ; do ... ; done`

Comment: @konsolebox Do you mean that even in case of `while true ; do ... ; done` or `while : ; do ... ; done` a bash built-in `true` or `:` is called while `(( ;; ))` is condition built into the bash for-loop itself and thus more efficient?

Comment: @Martin I think it's time I examine the source code to verify my claims :)

Comment: @konsolebox Well I upvoted your answer so I am waiting to see what you find!

Comment: @jaypal It's not really something to take seriously as it's not really part of the question's main concern. Unlike builtins, `for` and `while` is difficult to find in the source code but this is a start: $ time ( while true; do (( ++i == 100000 )) && break; done; )
real    0m0.556s
user    0m0.555s
sys     0m0.001s

$ time ( for (( ;; )); do (( ++i == 100000 )) && break; done; )
real    0m0.511s
user    0m0.502s
sys     0m0.009s

Comment: @konsolebox `:)` I know ... pun intended!

Comment: Everything can be found in [execute_cmd.c](https://github.com/teknopaul/binjs/blob/master/bash-4.2/execute_cmd.c). Compare `execute_while_or_until()` with `eval_arith_for_expr()`. It's only `execute_while_or_until()` that calls `execute_command()` for testing the condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ test ""; echo $?
1
```

So may be 'test' evaluates any non-empty string as a success (0),
and empty string ("") as a failure (1).

Comment: Maybe? It's pretty explicitly documented.